# URL Redirect php or .htaccess in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress blog, and having issue with URL's..
Few months ago i used link with slug (Forcely changed to blog when i switched to MultiSite) like this, **example.com/blog**

Now I am using wordpress without **BLOG** and removed slug "BLOG" after link.

Problem is many quality backlinks i have with **old blog slug**.
When someone visit my blog with **example.com/blog/post-permalink** it redirects to *not_found_404* error because link should be looks like this, **example.com/post-permalink**.

I am confused, how to redirect every request that comes with **example.com/blog/post-name** and redirect to **example.com/post-name**

Comment: There are hundreds of redirect plugins you could use, I like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

Comment: yes but i want to solve this issue by using .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Redirecting pages below /blog/

It should be as simple as a .htaccess in your domain root directory (where index.php lives) with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that `RewriteEngine on` is required only once per .htaccess file, so skip this if it is present already.

The `RewriteRule` itself matches all URL beginning (`^`) with `blog/` and catches everything following until the end (`$`). The caught part is stored in the reference `$1`.

This reference is thereafter used in the redirection target, as `/$1`.

`L` means that no further rules in the .htaccess are evaluated.

`R=301` redirects using a HTTP/1.1 301 Permanent redirect, which is desirable for SEO and redirects all visitors to the new URL.

## Redirecting /blog itself

In addition to the above insert

```
RewriteRule ^blog(/?)$ / [L,R=301]
```